# Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: count

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
    public employee getCurrentEmployee(){
        var name = User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 9).ToLower();
        var emp = db.employees.Where(x => x.NT_Name == name && x.active_flag == true).FirstOrDefault();
        return emp;
    }
```

when I run it using Web Forms it works well but in the MVC it gots this error

> Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: count

note: I am new in programming.
really need help, thanks :)

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` length is probably less than 10?

Comment: I eliminate the " .Remove(0, 9) " and I got this error HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found

The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Your `User.Identity.Name` string is less than the amount you want to remove.

You should check the `Length` of the string first, before trying to remove something.